# Wrapfigure: skip some lines

Tags: pdftex, positioning, wrapfigure

I am having a wrapfigure at the bottom of my page in the last paragraph which refuses a nice looking position.

x -> text, # -> wrapfigure:

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ##################################
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ##################################
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ######### some equation ##########
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ##################################
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ##################################
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

Because the equation is relatively small, I do not want that much whitespace. I want the text to float under **and** above the wrapfigure, like this (the whole paragraph is 14 lines long, so there is enough space):

```
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx    
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ##################################
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ######### some equation ##########
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx ##################################
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The wrapfigure (in the code) is above the paragraph and whenever I move it down in the paragraph (even in the middle of the first sentence) it instantly moves to the next page.

Code looks like this:

```
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{R}{0.5\textwidth}
    \begin{small}
        \begin{gather}
            I_{in} =
            \begin{bmatrix}
                46 & 42 & 50 \\
                44 & 65 & 56 \\
                41 & 52 & 58 \\
            \end{bmatrix}
            \\
            I_{out}(2,2) = 131
        \end{gather}
    \end{small}
\end{wrapfigure}
% paragraph...
```

Comment: What is the `small` environment?

Comment: The matrix (bmatrix) is perfectly readable in small text size and was a bit too big in normal text size...hence, I made the matrix small(er).

Comment: Yes, but there is no ‘small’ environment in standard LaTeX, as far as I know. You have to use the `\small` switch.

Comment: I read this solution somewhere, I'm not remembering where it was. It was suggested, for long texts, math environments, ... to use `\begin` and `\end`     to create a `small` environment. I could not tell if this is common practice...but it works^^

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can what you want with the `plaintex` package `insbox`. It defines `\InsertBoxL` and `\InsertBoxR` commands, with two arguments: the number of untouched lines before inserting the box, and the contents of the box. Also an optional argument: the number of supplementary wrapped lines, if the height of the box is not correctly calculated.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\input{insbox.tex}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\InsertBoxR{3}{%
\parbox{0.5\linewidth-4mm}{\small
    \begin{gather}
        I_\text{in} =
        \begin{bmatrix}
            46 & 42 & 50 \\
            44 & 65 & 56 \\
            41 & 52 & 58 \\
        \end{bmatrix}
        \\[0.5ex]
        I_\text{out}(2,2) = 131
    \end{gather}}}[2]%
Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. But the words bleed into the box, i.e at the `line` with `I_{in}`

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: I think it isn't related to insbox, only  a hyphenation problem in the context of shorter lines and comparatively short word. Maybe a text in German would not show any problem :o)

Comment: It wasn't meant as criticism... Just noted it. And no, not any word in German can be hyphenated at will;-)

Comment: I didn't take it as a criticism. I just meant you have more possibilities for hyphenation with longer words. And  the German language has on average longer words than, say, French, due to the structure of the language. I also might have chosen Cymric or Greek!

Comment: Looks like what I want, but pdftex says `insbox.sty not found` when I implement `\usepackage{insbox}`. Maybe the name of the package is wrong? I have texlive-full...

Comment: Ooops! Sorry. Actually , as I said, it is a `plain tex` set of macros. I made a latex wrapper for it once, adding a couple of commands that I found useful , but it's not an official package. I've  corrected with the real syntax. If you're interested, I can upload the personal `insbox.sty` file, but you'll have to install it, or keep it with the main file.

Comment: It is working with `\input{insbox}`...s̶t̶r̶a̶n̶g̶e̶?̶ Edit: Thank you for your explanation! It is working perfectly now, without any bleeding edges, but it is causing some weird behaviour: the next section ("Research and field of application") is now splitted in two lines. Even `\clearpage` or `\newpage` has no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: Could you post a minimal example illustrating the problem? I suspect next section simply to be too close from the insertion point, but it's easier to check what happens on a concrete example.

Comment: Normal title of the section http://abload.de/img/screenshotfrom2015-06abxf3.png and broken title http://abload.de/img/screenshotfrom2015-06l4yjs.png. The paragraph before this section is relatively long...the page before this page holds the insbox.

Comment: Strange… I'll try to experiment. What is your document class? Do you load any package that interfere with sections formatting?

Comment: Try to remove the optional argument (`[2]`) and see what happens.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve this effect with `wrapfig.sty`.  In its documentation, you find:

> **Placment and floating**
>   Parameter #2 (required) is the figure placement code, but the valid codes are different from regular figures. They come in pairs: an uppercase version which allows the figure to float, and a lowercase version that puts the figure "exactly here". [...]
>   It is convenient to begin the environment between paragraphs, but if you want
>   placement in the middle of a paragraph, you must put the environment between
>   two words where there is a natural line break.

Replace `R` with `r` and find a natural line break in your paragraph to start with `\begin{wrapfigure}`.  E.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern,wrapfig,amsmath}
\begin{document}

Wrapfig.sty provides the environments wrapfigure and wraptable for
typesetting a narrow float at the edge of the text, and making the
text wrap around
\begin{wrapfigure}[8]{r}{0.5\textwidth}
  \small
  \begin{gather}
    I_{in} =
    \begin{bmatrix}
      46 & 42 & 50 \\
      44 & 65 & 56 \\
      41 & 52 & 58 \\
    \end{bmatrix}
    \\
    I_{out}(2,2) = 131
  \end{gather}
\end{wrapfigure}
it. The wrapfigure and wraptable environments interact properly with
the \verb|\caption| command to produce proper numbering, but they are
not regular floats like figure and table, so (beware!)  they may be
printed out of sequence with the regular floats.  [...]  Parameter
\verb|#2| (required) is the figure placement code, but the valid codes
are different from regular figures. They come in pairs: an uppercase
version which allows the figure to float, and a lowercase version that
puts the figure ``exactly here''.
\end{document}
```

> [image]